# Excel Date field slicer shows extra values

Tags: excel, date, pivot-table, slicers

I have a table with a date field with different values for years 2016 and 2017. When I make a Pivot Chart and set the slicer for years, I get this:

[image]

How do I get rid of those `<1/1/2016` and `>12/2/2017` values? I have no date that is earlier than 1/1/2016 or later than 12/2/2017 in my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the Slicer, then Slicer Settings. Tick the box "Hide items with no data".

Screenshot is XL 2016. In earlier versions your mileage may vary.

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you. This appears to be not so complicated.

Comment: Well, this hides also the items in a filtered list if the items are missing in this particular filter, but are there for other filters. It looks like these extra filter fields appear for Excel automatic time grouping fields only.